# Saving plots in a data.table list column

Tags: r, plot, graph, data.table

When I run...

```
library(data.table)
DT = CJ(id = 1, id2 = 1:3)[, .(
    d = as.IDate("2017-01-01")+1:10, v = id*10 + id2*1:10
), by=.(id, id2)]

plotDT = DT[, {
    par(mfrow = c(uniqueN(id2), 1), mar = c(2,2,.5,2))
    .SD[,{ 
        plot(d, v, type="l")
    }, by=id2]
    .(p = .(recordPlot()))
}, by=id]

x11()
plotDT[id == 1L, replayPlot(p[[1]])]
```

The plot from `DT[...]` is correct:

[image]

While the replay is wrong:

[image]

In the recordedplot, the final values of `x` and `y` are magically applied to all three graphs, probably because of how data.table handles pointers to columns defined in `by=` groups.

I'm not really sure I understand what's going on, though, because I can change the example superficially, writing `v = id2*1:10` instead of `v = id*10 + id2*1:10` and -- poof -- the problem disappears.

I'd like to know (i) why is this happening and (ii) what simple tweak can I make to get around it?

Comment: Unsurprisingly, one workaround is to make sure the variable is passed by value by using `v + 0` in place of `v`. That's what I'll do until I hear of a better way.

Comment: When I run this code, I get the same result for the normal DT plot and the recordplot (both the wrong one). However, when I switch to `v = id2*1:10`, I indeed get the right result for both.

Comment: @takje Huh, I wonder if we have a different version or something. I'm using R 3.2.4 and data.table 1.10.4

Comment: I tested this with R version 3.3.2. Data table version is the same.

Comment: Hm, okay, I updated R and still see exactly what I saw in the OP... filing a bug.

Comment: Resizing the plot window gives the same result as `replayPlot`

Comment: @user3226167 Interesting, thanks for the observation. Btw, here's the bug report: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2050

Comment: This may be a broader bug in recordPlot. When I put two plots in a list with recordPlot and then play them back for pdf output, I just see the first plot repeating... Forum threads show the "just use lattice" line, but it does not seem to have a decent analogue for `curve()`...

Comment: For my future ref: `with(copy(.SD), {yada j})` is an adequate workaround so far. Ref http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43536583/data-table-not-returning-correct-plots?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment74148898_43548292

Comment: If you posted your workaround as an answer, this question would get moved off the unanswered questions queue.

Comment: @42- Is that sufficient? I don't intend to accept it, as I'd rather wait for a bug fix or something less hacky, but I can post it and will do so now.

Comment: I don't see why it would be insufficient. (I was suspecting that the first plots were handled by data.table and the next ones by "ordinary R" with different strategies of lazy evaluation.)

Comment: @42- Yeah, that sounds plausible; thanks. Anyway, I would prefer to leave it open. Hope that doesn't mess up the queue too much. (It's a list not a queue, right? I don't see it here https://stackoverflow.com/review )

Answer (score 2):

One working hack is to write `j` like

```
with(copy(.SD), {yada yada})
```

or similar, which ensures that references are to the per-group copy of `.SD` and don't get conflated.