# Data.table not returning correct plots

Tags: r, plot, data.table

Starting to learn data.table package and wanted to try plotting.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(iris)

DT[, plot(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, main = Species), by = Species]
```

Does not return same as for example

```
DT1 <- DT[Species == "setosa"]
DT1[, plot(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, main = Species)]
```

The second one shows all observations, while the first one does not.

Is there a perfect logical explanation that I have not learned yet? Or something wrong with my graphics?

Comment: Maybe related to this bug http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42449257/saving-plots-in-a-data-table-list-column I'm not sure what you're doing with `plot` like that if you haven't called `par()` before it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem and a workaround have been reported in [Saving plots in a data.table list column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42449257/3817004).

It seem that the issue is related to base `plot()` as `ggplot2` is working as expected, e.g.,

```
library(data.table)
DT[, print(ggplot(.SD, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, color = Species)) +
             geom_point()), by = Species]
```

creates a series of three plots which are displayed in RStudio's Plots pane, for instance. The first one looks like:

[image]

However, with base `plot()`

```
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
DT[, plot(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, main = Species), by = Species]
```

some data points have been clipped off:

[image]

As mentioned by *Frank* [in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42449257/saving-plots-in-a-data-table-list-column#comment72043360_42449257) *one workaround is to make sure the variable is passed by value*, e.g, by adding `0`. So, this workaround will create a base plots with all data points included:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
DT[, plot(Sepal.Length + 0, Sepal.Width + 0, main = Species), by = Species]
```

[image]

Note that `0` has to be added to both variables.

**EDIT** In case of working with *non-numeric data* (so adding `0` isn't viable), *Frank* [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43536583/data-table-not-returning-correct-plots/43548292?noredirect=1#comment74148898_43548292) to use another approach to pass the data *by value*:

```
DT[, with(copy(.SD), plot(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, main = Species)), by = Species]
```

Comment: In case one is working with non-numeric data (so +0 isn't viable), maybe `DT[, with(copy(.SD), plot(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, main = Species)), by = Species]`

Answer (score 0):

In the first part you are trying to plot the two variables per level of Species. Try to alter par to see what you are trying to achieve:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
DT[, plot(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, main = Species), by = Species]
```

In the second instance you plot iris but without specifying a conditional variable, repeating the main column (I think!)

Comment: I have tried plotting using mfrow(c(2, 2)), but I dont understand why the plots are "incorrect". If I want to calculate group per mean, it is not a problem. Why should it cause problem when replacing plot for mean?

Comment: Ah apologies, did not catch your question. It does indeed seem quite strange, I am not sure why this happens. If subsetting for versicolor/virginica there is no problem weirdly enough so it's not the first factor level per se.

Comment: Pf, complex stuff, cannot figure it out. It seems plot overrides the `by=` command in DT, whatever you do only the full dataset is plotted (`DT[,plot(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width,main=Species,xlim=c(4.5,8),ylim=c(2,3.4)),by=Species]`). One option would be to first output the desired columns and plot the result. Good luck!

Comment: Above works, but is not a optional option. will see if the author checks in and have a solution.