# rmarkdown data.table plots don't match after compilation

Tags: r, data.table, r-markdown

I've looked everywhere for an answer and I'm not sure if this is a bug, but I haven't found any remotely similar issues for this, so here goes.

I'm (relatively) new to the `data.table` library in R, but its ability to easily apply stuff to selective queries without having to make a function for everything had me sold the moment I first used it.

I compile reports with rmarkdown, and have been running plots on the `j` part of the `DT[i, j, by]`. This works smoothly in Rstudio, the editor executes my code the way it's supposed to but the moment I compile the output, the plots don't match what I want (and saw) anymore !

I've cleaned and restarted my Rsession multiple times, so I know this issue is not due to my R environment. Even stranger, when I actually print the data in the `j` code, they are the same in both the output and the editor, so `plot` is really the one messing this up...

Here is Rmd code that illustrates my problem :

````
---
title: "data.table plot issue"
author: "Anyone"
date: "27 juin 2018"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## Building data

```{r}
library(data.table)

tab = data.table(varA = rep(1:4, each=5),
                 varB = rep(1:5, 4),
                 varC = rep(LETTERS[1:4], each=5),
                 varD = rep(c("red", "blue", "green", "hotpink"), each=5))
tab
```

```{r results="hold"}
layout(matrix(1:4, nrow = 2, byrow = T))
a = tab[,{

  print(varA)
  print(varB)
  print(varC)
  print(varD)

  plot(varB, varA, col=varD, ylim=c(0,5), pch=16, main=varC)

  }, by=varC ]
```
````

This is what I get in Rstudio (which is what I should) :
[image]
[image]

However, *this* is what I get after compilation :

[image]

The printed variables are correct, so I don't know what the problem is here. I assume it has to do with Rmarkdown compilation and the way it handles plots but I don't have much to go on.

Any ideas ?

---

*Edit :*

Version info :

- `R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)`
- `knitr_1.20`
- `rmarkdown_1.9`

Comment: I can reproduce the problem, my version of the package is: `rmarkdown_1.9`, `knitr_1.20` and `data.table_1.11.0`. I am running on: 

`R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)`

Comment: Maybe maybe related to [Plot series inside data.table call when grouping](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1524)

Comment: @Henrik Maybe, but it's strange that here we get the opposite effect (Rstudio output is good while the compiled one is not)

Answer (score 0):

You can force the colours by surrounding the colour with `paste0`:

```
layout(matrix(1:4, nrow = 2, byrow = T))
a = tab[,{

  print(varA)
  print(varB)
  print(varC)
  print(varD)
  plot(varB, varA, col=paste0(varD), ylim=c(0,5), pch=16, main=varC)
  }, by=varC ]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that could do it *in this case*. Unfortunately, the data column(s) that plot has trouble with depend on the data. On this example, it's the colors and the title, but on some of my reports, the actual points of the plots are affected (it plots the same *y* values for all plots, and the colors are correctly assigned). I hope that I won't have to do such fixes for all my plots. Thanks for your input though :)

Comment: Ah but the principle is the same: force evaluation. For example, `plot(varB, varA + 0, ...)`

Comment: Does assigning the variable not cause evaluation ? I tried doing something like `A = varA` and then `plot(A, B, ...)` during my tests

Comment: Try `A = varA + 0`.

Comment: Yes, I guessed *that* would work. I'm wondering why just `A = varA` doesn't ? And while I'm at it, do you know of a way to force evaluation independantly of variable type (or at least for numeric, chars and factors) ?

Comment: `copy(varA)` will duplicate the value

Comment: Did you know `force()`?

Comment: Re having to do such fixes on all plots @RomainB. I guess this might work generally (I didn’t test with your example): https://stackoverflow.com/a/44146260/1191259